# Отправка Jquery.load() методом post в Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel

В шаблоне: `$("#ajax-box-1").load("table", { table: table });`

В файле web.php: `Route::post('table', [GetTableDataController::class, 'table']);`

Контроллер GetTableDataController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Element;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GetTableDataController extends Controller
{
    public function table(Request $request)
    {
        return view('base', ['r' => Element::all()]);
    }
}
```

Сервер возвращает ошибку "500 (Internal Server Error)".

Дополнительный вопрос: что такое post('table'?

Comment: `Route::post('table' ***)` сообщает маршрутизатору что по маршруту site.ru/table должен приходить пост запрос, ошибка у вас может быть связана с тем что  у вас запрос идёт к `table` то есть находясь на странице к примеру site.ru/page2 запрос будет идти site.ru/page2/table и сам запрос будет типа гет насколько я помню jq

Comment: Так, вроде завел. Передал csrf-token и очистил кэш командой: php artisan route:cache. Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: Но Laravel все еще довольно часто выдает ошибку: "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST"

Comment: Так я же говорю, jq.load это гет запрос, а роут ждёт пост запрос, если у вас роут не управляет стейтами приложения отдавайте его в гете, зачем вам такой роут который только возвращает в пост пихать?

Comment: Это не get, а POST - jq.load с аргументом в виде объекта { table: table } шлет post запрос + у меня в отладчике он виден как POST

Answer (score 0):

Load вроде ajax запрос. Попробуйте в контроллере вместо return view('base', ['r' => Element::all()]); использовать что то типа return response()->json([ view(''base', ['r' => Element::all()])->render()], 200); Я еще в Laravel 6 пишу, возможно в 8 это пишется немного по другому.